# Did I state correctly a logic theorem?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am asked to write formally the Soundness theorem for predicate FOL. I write it. Could you check it and see if I stated  correctly or not?

**Theorem**

FOL is sound respect to the proposed test theory $(A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5,MP,$ Generalization rule), i.e. $$\vdash_{FOL}\phi\implies\vDash_{FOL}\phi$$

where $\vdash$ denotes theorem, $\vDash$ denotes a formula it's valid under every interpretation, $A_i$ are the axioms $(A_1,A_2,A_3$ are the same as in propositional logic).

Comment: Theorems of this sort are usually called "soundness"; I've never seen "robustness" with this meaning --- perhaps it's the result of translation by someone who knows the languages but not the technical terminology. Also, I guess that "classic logic" is intended to mean propositional logic (since you contrast it with FOL), and I think "Generalized rule" is intended to mean the rule of generalization. In the statement of the theorem, $\vDash$ should denote validity (meaning truth in **all** interpretations).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Oh so it's called soundness, that's why I didn't find anything related to it on google.

Comment: "Generalization rule".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes that's what I wanted to say:) btw it's correct the theorem?

Comment: See [Soundness Theorem for Predicate Logic](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/alexc/logic/soundness.pdf); basically $\vDash$ means *valid*, with respect to the semantics for the specific language; in your case: predicate logic. Thus, I tìhink that you can omit the subscript in $\vDash_{FOL}$.

Comment: For the other comment, see Blass' one: *valid* is "true in every interpretation"; thus "valid under every interprettaion" is a little bit redundant.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see, thank you.